# MVC and a card game

Tags: model-view-controller, observers

I'm designing a card game and I want to follow the MVC pattern. Is the concept below fine? It's language agnostic (not written in any actual programming language).

```
class GameModel
{
   Player p[maxPlayers];
   Deck d;
   Rules r;

   method nextTurn()
   {
      p[activePlayer].makeTurn( ...some paramaters...);
      ...
   }

   method addObserver(int classID, int index, Observer o)
   {
     switch(classID)
     {
        case id_model:
           this.addObserver(o);
           break;

        case id_deck:
           d.addObserver(o);
           break;

        case id_player:
           p[index].addObserver(o);
           break;

       ...
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the View will need to know things like "how many cards does this player have?", shall I write (in the Model) methods like:

```
method cardCount(int playerNr)
{
    return p[playerNr].cardCount();
}
```

or shall I solve this via the Observer pattern (the View would observe players and they would notify the View about the cards drawn or thrown).

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Caroline